# Create a vector graphics (svg, eps, pdf) "heatmap" from 2d function with colorbar

Tags: python, plot, gnuplot, vector-graphics

I want to plot a 2d hanning window function for a picture with `N=512` pixels with a colorbar as vector graphics (`*.svg`, `*.eps`, (vectorized!) `*.pdf` or so)...
So I need to plot a 2d function

```
w(x,y) = sin(x*pi/N)^2 * sin(y*pi/N)^2
```

My solution for this was `python` first:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im_hanning = Image.new("F", (N, N))
pix_hanning = im_hanning.load()

for x in range(0, N):
    for y in range(0, N):
        pix_hanning[x,y] = np.sin(x*np.pi/N)**2 * np.sin(y*np.pi/N)**2 * 255

im_hanning = Image.fromarray(array)
```

The result is this picture:
[image: hanning window with python]

But this is a raster graphics of course.

So I tried it with `gnuplot`. This seemed better until I saw the result:

```
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
unset xtics
unset ytics

set pm3d map
set size square

set samples 512
set isosamples 512
set palette gray

splot sin(x*pi)**2 * sin(y*pi)**2
```

I had to increase the samples, else it looked terrible... The result looks fine:
[image: hanning window function with gnuplot]

I especially like the colorbar on the right. But this produces (no matter what terminal I set) raster graphics again.

**Is there a possibility to plot a 2d function as vector graphics?**

Comment: Oh and what I see just now: The images' gradient isn't identical, right? What is the "right" gradient, what's wrong? Do I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

With a PDF, SVG or EPS terminal, gnuplot **does** give you vector graphics. **But** the function has to be represented in some way, and what gnuplot does is a piecewise linear interpolation, that is, the surface is represented by small portions of plane (triangles or quadrangles), the number of which is set by the sampling rate.

If you want an infinitely scalable colour map, the way to produce it has to be a primitive of the scalable vector language you are using, e.g. SVG. So this is your real question: is there an SVG/PDF/EPS primitive to represent the gradient `sin(x*pi)**2 * sin(y*pi)**2`. I believe this is not the case, colour gradients are also piecewise linear AFAIK, but asked in this way you may attract answers from specialists.

Comment: Thanks for pointing into the right direction. And of course I get vector graphics - but not the ones I wanted to get.